# Stata failing to call global variable?

Tags: stata

The following simple thing doesn't work.

```
global inputfolder "C:\Users\Focus\Google Drive\1. hani and\Raw data\2004"

cd $inputfolder
```

It says

```
invalid syntax
```

But if I do

```
global inputfolder "C:\Users"

cd $inputfolder
```

Then it works. I tried, among others, adding "="

```
global inputfolder="C:\Users\Focus\Google Drive\1. hani and\Raw data\2004"
```

but it didn't help.

What should I do to make the first thing work?

Answer (score 4):

When you write

```
global inputfolder "C:\Users\Focus\Google Drive\1. hani and\Raw data\2004"
cd $inputfolder
```

Stata substitutes the global reference with the contents of the global, so that `cd` sees

```
cd C:\Users\Focus\Google Drive\1. hani and\Raw data\2004
```

but the spaces are then problematic. This advice is prominent in the help for `cd` (see e.g. http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?cd):

> If your directory_name contains embedded spaces, remember to enclose
>   it
>           in double quotes.

Hence all you need is

```
cd "$inputfolder"
```

Note that the difference between copying a string into a global and assigning a string to a global indeed makes no difference here, as the problem is entirely in feeding `cd` a string it can't understand.

On a point of terminology, note that global macros are not regarded as variables in Stata. That term is reserved for columns in the dataset.